# Can I Programmatically Discern IIS Server Settings? (MaxConnections, etc.)

Tags: iis, signalr, web-hosting

I am attempting to run a SignalR application (.NET 4.5) on an inexpensive shared hosting provider, and I have read that IIS can begin to throttle connections if the server settings are allocated too low.  Since I don't have admin control of this server, is there a way I can programmatically check the server settings like the maximum connections per CPU, etc?

Comment: How many connections would you expect inexpensive shared hosting to give you?

Comment: I really don't know; it's just a question.  I haven't run into many limitations with this provider, but it might be that the terrain is a little different due to the nature of SignalR and long polling.  It sounds like you're suggesting that it's unreasonable for the default settings of an ASP.NET host to work well with SignalR given what it's trying to do?  I'm not trying to be naive or obtuse; just asking.  Most providers don't advertise "simultaneous number of connections supported" but it sounds like this is becoming more relevant with the advent of SignalR.